# edition of 3d models in Meshlab

Tags: meshlab

i would like to know if it is possible to make actions like hollow and/or plane cut to a 3d model (STL or OBJ), with Meshlab. 
I normally use Meshlab to aply filters and i love it because i use a large quantity of 3d models an with Meshlab i can open them unattended and Meshlab load the geometries really fast.

If it is not possible to do it with Meshlab, do you know any 3d software that load the 3d models as fast as MeshLab that can do it?

Hope to find a solution that helps me to work better, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can make a model hollow using filters -> Remeshing, Simplication -> Uniform mesh resampling, and making the offset negative.  Through my experience the precision needs to be half or less than the absolute value of the offset.  This process can take a long time for large meshes.

As far as other programs, I use a python script to load meshes into Blender and perform a "Smart UV Unwrap" without opening the program.  So anything you can do in blender can be done from the commandline:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/how-can-i-run-blender-from-command-line-or-a-python-script-without-opening-a-gui